# "Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray" error on Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get a response from my API with Android.

What I am trying to do is to get the `JSONArray` as a response from my API but I am getting the following error:

> Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

The response that I am sending from my API is:

```
[
   {
      "name1":"Peter",
      "name2":"Andrew"
   }
]
```

And this is the code that I am using to retrieve it from Android:

```
JsonArrayRequest JsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
{
   @Override public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
       if(response!=null){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data has been sent correctly.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          finish();
       }else{
       }
   }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
});
```

but it always goes to the error block.

I know that there are a lot of questions related about this error but most of them are related about a wrong JSON creation. I think that it is not the problem here as I have created it as JsonArray are created in [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) but in this case with only one element on the array (instead of two, as the example on the javadocs).

How can I avoid to get this error if I am already using a JSONArray?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the server and getting the response you "think" your API is sending? Try using Charles Proxy -  It will show you exactly what your API is sending the client.

Comment: As said by @Zain try to check the response in postman and double check it

Comment: name1 and name2 You're trying to be

Comment: @Zain I am checking that I am getting the response from my API with Postman application and it is the response that I am showing on the question.

Comment: @SomasundaramMahesh Yes, I know that I am getting that response beacuse I am checking it with postman application.

Comment: @Error404 try adding headers Accept : application/json to your request

Comment: @Error404 any luck?

Comment: @SomasundaramMahesh Yes, I have added them too. It is very strange because if I use it on postman the function works well (it sends an email) and gives to me the response. On Android I am getting this error, instead.

Comment: @Error404 use StringRequest and then change it to JSONArray when you want to parse it.

Comment: @SomasundaramMahesh I have used StringRequest now and it is going to onSuccess block now but it is not getting the response. If I try it with postman, it works like a charm.

Comment: Can you ping me the url

Comment: @SomasundaramMahesh I am sorry but I cannot provide the url because it is of a personal client and I cannot provide it. Is there some way to put something on php and look where Android is entering? I suspect that Android is entering in a different way on the API or doing some other stuff (although the url is the same).

Comment: @SomasundaramMahesh Finally I got the solution, the problem was on the url. I have posted an example on the answer below :D. Thank you for the help provided ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of debugging and looking at my code, I found that my problem was that I had a space between the elements on the url. As follows:

```
String url = "http://myIP/application/getNames/{\"user\":\"user192\", \"password\":\"" + passwordText + "\"}";
                                                                     ^
```

It seems that `Postman` application does not care about that space and call the API without spaces (because from Postman the request worked well) but when you are trying to send the request from Android it takes in consideration that space and does not modify the url, it tries to call the API as the url points. Therefore, the data is not being retrieved in your API as normally.

When you remove that space, it works like a charm.

**P.S.**: As `@SomasundaramMahesh` pointed out, I had to use a `StringRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest`. I could not understand why I had to change it, as I am retrieving a `JSONArray`.